# Accessing many text files in java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, file-handling, large-data

I have to read 20 odd compartively big files (mostly txt or pdf in some cases) and then perform some text processing on them .

I am using a BufferedReader and a loop to read these files , is there an effective way to do this ?

My problem : Read the contents of these files and seperate them into tokens and then store them in a data structure . I am using an array now , but i would like to make use of an efficient structure .

Can somebody suggest a means to solve both these problems

Comment: Instead of Array use List or Map...

Comment: You are on right track (Reading files content using BufferedReader) but you need to define a class that holds tokens. Don't use arrays, use List or Map instead.

Comment: I thought with Maps , the key value pairs would bring in more complexity .. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Define "token" and why do you want to do this...sometimes knowing the end goal can help provide better solutions

Comment: I have to split the document into words and then find the term frequency of these words . I am using the in built function split to divide the document . Since the results is a String array , i am in a position to use an array instead of a list

Comment: Maybe you should try Apache Lucene - if your primary concern is searching/ indexing. Load your files in any way to it and let it handle the "tough" part for you !

Comment: If you put each word into a map as the name, then increment it's value by one for every occurrence you find, the word frequency can be added up line by line (word by word).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are counting the frequency of each word you should use a list then iterate through the list and use a map with the key being the word to keep track of the number of occurences

Comment: The problem with this method in my case is i create a dictionary from the set of words and then the tfs are based on the every document . hence every word will have have more than one number  assoicated with it ! So i cant be using a map

Comment: You can implement a custom type for the value side of the map or use a map of maps

Comment: Thanks i will try implementing it !